# How do I switch nsarray object from one index to another

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I need a way to switch an image texture from one index to another in an nsmutable array.

```
balloonTextures = [NSMutableArray array];

    // Add each of the balloon textures into the balloon textures array
    [balloonTextures addObject:[SPTexture textureWithContentsOfFile:@"greentutorial.png"]];
    [balloonTextures addObject:[SPTexture textureWithContentsOfFile:@"redtutorial.png"]];

    SPImage *image = [SPImage imageWithTexture:[balloonTextures objectAtIndex:0]];
    image.x = 0;
    image.y = 10 ;
    [playFieldSprite addChild:image];
    [image addEventListener:@selector(onTouchBalloon:) atObject:self forType:SP_EVENT_TYPE_TOUCH];
```

As you can see I have an NSMutableArray with an image that contains the image texture greentutorial. Now I want to switch it with a red texture (red tutorial) with this method that is called in 20 seconds.

```
 -(void)changeColor{

 image = [SPImage imageWithTexture:[balloonTextures objectAtIndex:1]];

  }
```

However, it isn't working at all. I know the image is getting called on because if I add the code below in the method and it works.

```
  image.x = 300;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To switch the index,

```
-(void) swapTexturesAtIndex:(int) index1 and:(int) index2{
    id temp1 = [balloonTextures objectAtIndex:index1];
    id temp2 = [balloonTextures objectAtIndex:index2];
    [balloonTextures replaceObjectAtIndex:index1 withObject:temp2];
    [balloonTextures replaceObjectAtIndex:index2 withObject:temp1];
}
```

EDIT 1:

Why don't you just use something like this,

```
-(void)changeImageTextureFromIndex:(int) index{

 image = [SPImage imageWithTexture:[balloonTextures objectAtIndex:index]];

  }
```

Comment: How would I add image into this method.